# Unable to use global variable with createElement inside loop

Tags: javascript, loops, variables, global, createelement

I am unable to create a global variable for a document.createElement('br') object and reuse it inside loops.  In the example, I show where can:

- Example 0: Call document.createElement('br') each time inside the loop, and each line of the output has a break.
- Example 1: Create a variable for document.createElement('br') each time inside the loop and use it, and each line of the output has a break.
- Example 2: When the variable for document.createElement('br') is created globally and used inside loop, the output is displayed with no breaks, "a: 1b: 2c: 3"

```js
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

/* Does work */
const div0 = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => div0.append(`${key}: ${obj[key]}`, document.createElement('br')))


/* Does work */
const div1 = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[1];
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    const br1 = document.createElement('br');
    div1.append(`${key}: ${obj[key]}`, br1);
    console.log(`${typeof(br1)}, ${br1}`, br1); // Used to verify I see the same results each time loop is run, and same results as br2
})

/* Does NOT work */
const div2 = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[2];
const br2 = document.createElement('br');
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    div2.append(`${key}: ${obj[key]}`, br2);
    console.log(`${typeof(br2)}, ${br2}`, br2); // Used to verify I see the same results each time loop is run, and same results as br1
})
```

```html
<div>Example 0: br Does work - createElement is called each time loop is run.<br></div><br>
<div>Example 1: br Does work - createElement is assigned to a variable each time loop is run.<br></div><br>
<div>Example 2: br Does NOT work - createElement is assigned to a global variable.<br></div>
```

Why is this not working, which would allow me to create once and reuse?  I also included some console.log output to show I am getting the same results for the varible itself in the working & not working examples.

Comment: You are creating **one** br element and then trying to put it in multiple places. Append puts it where you say. Append doesn’t copy it.

Comment: you could use `br2.cloneNode(true)`
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_clonenode.asp

Comment: When you append an element to the DOM, it becomes part of the DOM tree, and you can't simply reuse the same element in multiple places. You need to create a new element for each place you want to append it.

Comment: Understood. Thank you.